# How to backup Sequences in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Can we take the backup of sequences and use it in other databases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below SQL will return the list of SQL statement that can be executed on target to Reset value of sequence

```
SELECT 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || c.relname || ' RESTART WITH ' || nextval(c.relname::regclass) || ';' 
FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

Comment: I think this format can help us in other ways too, In case of creation of indexes etc. Thanks for the idea....!!!!

Comment: This doesn't work if you use sequences in multiple schemas. The other answer is working if you have that problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || s.relname || ' RESTART WITH ' || t.reltuples + 1 || ';'
FROM pg_class s 
  JOIN pg_depend d ON d.objid = s.oid 
  JOIN pg_class t ON d.objid = s.oid AND d.refobjid = t.oid 
  JOIN pg_attribute a ON (d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum)
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = s.relnamespace 
WHERE s.relkind = 'S' AND n.nspname = 'public'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using pg_dump

Don't write your own sequence-dumping code. Instead use PostgreSQL's `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall`

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( id serial PRIMARY KEY, other int );
INSERT INTO foo (other) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
```

Then dump it with `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall`,

```
$ pg_dump -t foo | grep -i pg_catalog.setval | grep "'public.foo"
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.foo_id_seq', 3, true);
```

Sequences are PostgreSQL specific. This dumps PostgreSQL code. This question is old, but instead of using sequences you can migrate your sequences to `IDENTITY COLUMNS`. Then they'll work in other SQL-compliant databases then.

## Migrate to IDENTITY COLUMNS

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  other int
);
INSERT INTO foo (other) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
```

then you can dump it with,

```sh
pg_dump -t foo | perl -nE'print if /GENERATED BY/ .. /\);/'
```

And you'll get back something like,

```sh
ALTER TABLE public.foo ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.foo_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);
```

This will *almost* work with [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.1/sqlreferencefornosql/alter-identity-columns.html)